# Issue with passing a value to Date Object

Tags: date, datetime, dojo

I am want to display a date in MM/yyyy format. I am using the below code to change the format :

```
 var inputDate = new Date(data);

            var date = dojo.date.locale.format(inputDate, {datePattern: "MM/yyyy", selector: "date"});
```

data contains the input date. For example when German Locale is set in the browser, the input value is like : 01.03.2016 05:30

while creating the date object with this value gives invalid Date though it works when the US locale is set in the browser.Please guide to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `locale.parse` to convert your localized date string into a date object, then convert the date object into the formatted date you want.

See this small example:

```js
var browserLocale = 'de',
    data = '01.03.2016 05:30';


require(["dojo/i18n", "dojo/date/locale"], function(i18n, locale){
    require([i18n.getL10nName("dojo/cldr", "gregorian", browserLocale)], function() {
        var dateObject = locale.parse(data, {formatLength: 'short', locale: 'de'});
        alert(locale.format(dateObject, {datePattern: "MM/yyyy", selector: "date"}));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```